Can coined terms be copyrighted?
J. R. R. Tolkien coined a term eucatastrophe which is a hopeful and sudden turn of events - he coined it in opposition to catastrophe, which has negative connotations.
Now, we know the Tolkien Estate has always tried to keep a monopoly over everything written by Tolkien, to the point they once released a statement that no one can use his invented languages even though, to my knowledge, languages cannot be copyrighted. However, can specific terms and phrases, such as eucatastrophe be copyrighted? Can one use this term in any way they wish or are there limits to what can be done?
Thank you in advance for your answers!

No
Can coined terms be copyrighted?
You can't copyright words as they don't fall under "original literary, dramatic, musical and artistic work, including illustration and photography" (https://www.gov.uk/copyright)
Can one use this term in any way they wish or are there limits to what can be done?
You can place a Trademark on words used in commerce, for example Microsoft, Google etc... However in order to Trademark a word it must be distinctive (unique or easily distinguishable from other phrases) https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5c7d2d6140f0b603d660beaf/tm-guide.pdf.
If the term eucatastrophe can be proven to be distinctive, not common and not misleading then it falls under Trademark laws (thus cannot be used).

IANAL, but I searched on trademark laws for the UK (using Perplexity), and got the following tidbits of information: (1) trademarks initially last for 10 years, but (2) they can be renewed indefinitely (unlike copyrights), but (3) trademarks must be genuinely used in commerce to maintain their validity. That third requirement would probably be eucatastrophe's undoing.

I rather don't think it falls under distinctive category ( posses the ability to direct consumers to the origin of the product immediately without consumers needing to be taught about the origin ), unless this phrase was written or spoken multiple times it doesn't constitute as a exclusively distinctive phrase associated with the franchise. (I am not that familiar with lord of the rings so maybe i am mistaken)

"in order to trademark a word it must be distinctive (unique or easily distinguishable from other phrases)": this is not the only criterion, of course, which explains why a word like "apple" can be a trademark.  Furthermore, whether a word is distinctive has little to do with uniqueness; a mark can be distinctive if it is arbitrary or descriptive, for example, as in Apple Computer (arbitrary) or Corsica Ferries (descriptive).

@phoog Don't forget Apple Corps, which ownes Apple Records - and who had a heavy lawsuit with Apple Computers about who of them was Apple... and which lead to a sound called "sosumi" :)

@Trish I think you mean "which."  But that's a very odd way of describing the dispute or the suit.
